# MagicalRecord trigger completion block too early

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

Yesterday I [asked an almost similar question here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036222/magicalrecord-finish-block-before-everything-is-saved-on-import), and it did fix my problem back then. Hoverever now I have the same problem again, but with the new implementation. After adding some more data to be imported I''m now in the same problem again. However this time it looks like the completion block for my `saveAndWait` is been triggered before it's done.

It's the JSON api there contain more data, and not the code itself.

Here is my current code:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    NSDictionary *jsonData = [responseObject valueForKey:@"responses"];
    [User importFromObject:jsonData inContext:localContext];

    NSArray *orders = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"responses.orders"];
    [Order importFromArray:orders inContext:localContext];

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save data");
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Saving done.");
    successful(@"Some text");
}];
```

As said there's nothing changed in the code, only the data received.

The log shows that "saving done" is called before all savings is done. This is the only place where I import data or are saving them.

```
2015-05-06 14:55:57.261 xxxx[43159:9057742] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:](0xfeea04) -> Created Context UNNAMED
2015-05-06 14:55:57.262 xxxx[43159:9057742] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setRootSavingContext:](0xfeea04) Set Root Saving Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7ae6cb20>
2015-05-06 14:55:57.263 xxxx[43159:9057742] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_newMainQueueContext](0xfeea04) Created Main Queue Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7ae73ee0>
2015-05-06 14:55:57.263 xxxx[43159:9057742] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setDefaultContext:](0xfeea04) Set Default Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7ae73ee0>
2015-05-06 14:55:58.915 xxxx[43159:9057742] POST 'xxxx'
2015-05-06 14:55:59.939 xxxx[43159:9057742] 200 'xxxx' [1.0249 s]
2015-05-06 14:55:59.957 xxxx[43159:9057742] POST 'xxxx'
2015-05-06 14:56:00.702 xxxx[43159:9057742] 200 'xxxx' [0.7454 s]
2015-05-06 14:56:10.534 xxxx[43159:9058195] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7af24cb0) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7af24cb0): *** UNNAMED ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
2015-05-06 14:56:10.535 xxxx[43159:9058195] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7af24cb0) → Save Parents? 1
2015-05-06 14:56:10.535 xxxx[43159:9058195] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7af24cb0) → Save Synchronously? 0
2015-05-06 14:56:10.541 xxxx[43159:9058195] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x7af24cb0) Context UNNAMED is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 2 inserted objects
2015-05-06 14:56:10.750 xxxx[43159:9058195] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ae6cb20) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7ae6cb20): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
2015-05-06 14:56:10.750 xxxx[43159:9058195] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ae6cb20) → Save Parents? 1
2015-05-06 14:56:10.750 xxxx[43159:9058195] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ae6cb20) → Save Synchronously? 0
2015-05-06 14:56:16.200 xxxx[43159:9058195] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x7ae6cb20) Context BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 2 inserted objects
2015-05-06 14:56:16.232 xxxx[43159:9058195] __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke21(0x7ae6cb20) → Finished saving: <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7ae6cb20): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
2015-05-06 14:56:16.233 xxxx[43159:9057742] Saving done.
2015-05-06 14:56:16.233 xxxx[43159:9057742] All data has been setup sucessfully
2015-05-06 14:56:16.255 xxxx[43159:9057742] Perform Segue To LoginSucessSegue from LoginViewController
2015-05-06 14:56:36.208 xxxx[43159:9057742] No data found. Show pull down to refresh
2015-05-06 14:56:36.208 xxxx[43159:9057742] No data found. Show pull down to refresh
2015-05-06 14:56:36.210 xxxx[43159:9057742] No data found. Show pull down to refresh
2015-05-06 14:56:36.211 xxxx[43159:9057742] No data found. Show pull down to refresh
2015-05-06 14:56:45.083 xxxx[43159:9058146] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ae3b550) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7ae3b550): *** UNNAMED ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
2015-05-06 14:56:45.083 xxxx[43159:9058146] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ae3b550) → Save Parents? 1
2015-05-06 14:56:45.084 xxxx[43159:9058146] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ae3b550) → Save Synchronously? 0
2015-05-06 14:56:45.084 xxxx[43159:9058146] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x7ae3b550) Context UNNAMED is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 9 inserted objects
2015-05-06 14:56:45.087 xxxx[43159:9058146] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ae6cb20) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7ae6cb20): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
2015-05-06 14:56:45.087 xxxx[43159:9058146] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ae6cb20) → Save Parents? 1
2015-05-06 14:56:45.091 xxxx[43159:9058146] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ae6cb20) → Save Synchronously? 0
2015-05-06 14:56:45.093 xxxx[43159:9060610] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x7ae6cb20) Context BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 9 inserted objects
2015-05-06 14:56:45.096 xxxx[43159:9060610] __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke21(0x7ae6cb20) → Finished saving: <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7ae6cb20): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
```

Is it because I'm not allowed to import and save multiple entities in a `saveWithBlock` or what is going on? - I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to update MagicalRecord to newest beta version. When asking the question my project was running on version 2.2 (a "stabil" version), and now it's on [v2.3.0-beta 5](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/tree/v2.3.0-beta.5), witch solved my problem.

Related issue can be found here: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/1003